# Selecting layers of a raster stack using a sliding windows as a step in R in for loop

Tags: r, loop, stack, for-loop

I would like to create a loop that every time selects the first ten layers of a raster stack, calculates their mean and saves it to a layer of a new raster stack. Also, I would like to have a step that works like a sliding window. So, in the first loop, it will select layers from 1:10, in the second loop it will select layers from 11:20, and so on.
So far, I have written the following code:

```
file_list=stack(myfile.nc)
mn = stack()
#
for(i in seq(1,length(file_list@layers), by=10)){ 
  mn[[i]] <- mean[[i]] # supposed to calculate the mean of the first ten layers
}
```

Comment: What does that code do? Does it run? What is `mean[[i]]`? Did you mean to write `mean(somethign)`? What's `file_list`? Does that `seq` call work?

Comment: @Spacedman, I have edited the question above. The seq call gives layers 1,10,20,30 etc, while I would to get layers 1-10,11-20,21-30 etc instead.

Comment: No, that `seq` call won't work. Have you tried it? For example, if the length is 100, then you get `seq(1:100, by=10)` which is an error. You probably meant `seq(1,100,by=10)`, but please test code that you post.

Comment: Yes, you were correct, I 've also changed that in the original post!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Spacedman commentaries, I recommend you to read some basic tutorials to know how to handle spatial objects in R. But I have an example of what you want to do.

Reproducible example, a raster stack of 100 layers:

```
library(raster)

set.seed(123)

r <- raster()

s1 <- list()

for (i in 1:100) {
  s1[[i]] <- setValues(r, rnorm(n = ncell(r)))
}

s1 <- stack(s1)
```

Compute mean by a moving window:

```
s2 <- list()

for (i in 1:10) {
 s2[[i]] <- calc(s1[[((i-1)*10 + 1):((i-1)*10 + 10)]], fun = mean, na.rm = T) 
}

s2 <- stack(s2)
```

Result:

```
s2

## class       : RasterStack 
## dimensions  : 180, 360, 64800, 10  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
## resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
## extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
## coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
## names       :   layer.1,   layer.2,   layer.3,   layer.4,   layer.5,   layer.6,   layer.7,   layer.8,   layer.9,  layer.10 
## min values  : -1.353835, -1.314173, -1.336899, -1.330095, -1.572422, -1.276887, -1.413552, -1.292723, -1.293121, -1.366087 
## max values  :  1.247697,  1.380478,  1.324504,  1.305732,  1.395083,  1.518274,  1.324168,  1.340525,  1.288073,  1.247176
```

Comment: Here's a quicker way of making a random stack of 3x4 by 50 layers `s = stack(brick(array(runif(3*4*50),dim=c(3,4,50))))`

Comment: @Spacedman thanks for your suggestion! I appreciate it

Comment: Dear aldo_tapia, thank you for your answer but what i actually mean by the "moving window", is that I would like to have a moving step in the for loop. So, in the first iteration I will have the mean of the first ten layers of the raster, in the second iteration I will have the following ten layers and so on.

Comment: Yes, actually is exactly what you mean. Test this `for (i in 1:10) print(((i-1)*10 + 1):((i-1)*10 + 10))`

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using `zApply`.

Create a test array of 50 3x4 layers:

```
a = array(runif(3*4*50),dim=c(3,4,50))
```

Convert to a Raster stack object (have to go via `brick`):

```
s = stack(brick(a))
```

The next step needs the object to have `Z` values, but they can be anything:

```
s = setZ(s, 1:nlayers(s))
```

Now make a vector of group indices:

```
layers = rep(1:5,rep(10,5))
layers
# [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
# [39] 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
```

Then apply mean over the layers grouped by the layer indices:

```
s10mean = zApply(s, by=layers,fun=mean)
```

This is now a brick with five layers with the means:

```
s10mean
# class       : RasterBrick 
# dimensions  : 3, 4, 12, 5  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
```

To check, first lets see what the mean of the 31st to 40th parts of the original array are:

```
apply(a[,,31:40],c(1,2),mean)
#          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]
#[1,] 0.5128400 0.4061487 0.5870473 0.2036074
#[2,] 0.4610763 0.4732387 0.4928084 0.4972154
#[3,] 0.6670825 0.5265644 0.5172894 0.4435808
```

and that should be the same as the values in the fourth layer of the output:

```
as.matrix(s10mean[[4]])
#          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]
#[1,] 0.5128400 0.4061487 0.5870473 0.2036074
#[2,] 0.4610763 0.4732387 0.4928084 0.4972154
#[3,] 0.6670825 0.5265644 0.5172894 0.4435808
```

Looks good.